# How to detect Copy event of WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application which contains a WebBrowser control. Now I want to handle the Copy event (Context menu -> Copy as well as Ctrl+C) of the WebBrowser control and do some of my own processing in that event.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way that I found out was this:

```
private void myBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    myBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0].AttachEventHandler("oncopy", SayHello);
}

public void SayHello(object obj,EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello"); //Do your stuff here.
}
```

This triggers even for Context menu copy event.

Answer (score 2):

As far as handling Control+C, you can wireup to the WebBrowser's [PreviewKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx) event and do:

```
private void webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyData.ToString() == "C, Control") {
        Debug.WriteLine("You pressed Control + C");
        // Handle here
    }
}
```

If you have your own context menu on the web browser with a Control + C copy item, handle its click event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was going through the over-complicated route of overriding WndProc and listening to Copy messages which somehow don't seem to fire for this control! Also I am constrained to not replace the default context menu. :( Using `Document` I can get to the `ContextMenuShowing`. Do you have any idea if we can trap the default Copy event too?

Comment: I would have to say no, at least not easily without alot of weird hacks. Even if you get the underlying IHTMLDocument2 DOM interface, the closest thing in there is the selection item, which gives you the active selection in the page, and even with a global mouse hook its still hard to determine if they clicked the copy menu item in the context menu. I also looked through IHTMLDocument3,4,5 and still nothing too useful

Comment: Seems like I will have to recreate the entire context menu and its functionality then. Thanks again for your help!